# How to create a one-to-one related record in a separate table during processing (save()) of a form?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

Here's the schema:

```
sf_guard_user
  columns:
    id              { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    username            { type: string }
    firstname           { type: string }
    lastname            { type: string }
    password            { type: string }
    salt, algorith, etc...

sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    id      { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    user_id     { type: integer }
    user_type   { type: integer }
  relations:
    User: { class: sfGuardUser, local: user_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignType: one, foreignAlias: Profile }
    Type: { local: type_id, foreign
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in the frontend:  I'm trying to allow the frontend user to create new user's... which I can do and all goes well.

Where I'm stuck: (1) during the save() process of creating the sf_guard_user, creating the new user's sf_guard_user_profile and setting the column value of 'user_id' to the primary key of the newly-created sf_guard_user (column 'id').  (2) Then also setting the column 'user_type' to 4.

I don't even know where to begin.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

This is my actions.class.php file (project/Source Files/apps/modules/users/actions):

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $sf_guard_user = $form->save();      
      $this->redirect('users/edit?id='.$sf_guard_user->getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not understanding right. When you configure correctly the sfGuardPlugin it takes care of the profile creation.

Let's review the process step by step:

1) First, configure correctly the sfGuardPlugin, add this to your app.yml

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    profile_class:      yourProfileClass
    profile_field_name: user_id
```

2) Save your user using the form:

```
$form->save();
```

3) Retrieve the newly created profile, and modify it:

```
$user = $form->getObject();
$profile = $user->getProfile();
$profile->setUserType(4);
$profile->save();
```

4) And you are done! I use this exact same method on one of my websites. So Me and my users are 100% sure this method works. Remember to set up correctly the sfGuardPlugin, it will create the profile even if you don't use it's admin generator;

Comment: Just an observance, though: the profile wasn't automatically created until AFTER setting the type...

Answer (score 0):

The sfGuardPlugin creates the profile automatically for you when configured correctly. In your app.yml add this piece of code:

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    profile_class:      sf_guard_user_profile
    profile_field_name: user_id
```

This will configure the plugin, to create a new profile whenever a new user is created (the actions to create a new profile are executed by the object, not the view. So it doesn't depends if you are using sfGuardPlugin own Admins, or if you are using yours).

Then in the sf_guard_user_profile class (sf_guard_user_profile.php), in the save method you can do this:

```
public function save(PropelCon $con = null)
{
  if ($this->isNew())
  {
    $this->setUserType(4);
  }
  parent::save();
}
```

This will set the UserType to 4, to any new profile.

Comment: Maybe I went about this the wrong way, but what I did was I created a new frontend "user" module with the same sfGuardUser schema, so I could have the usual index, show, edit, and new templates and their respective actions.  I needed to do it this way to have precise control over how these users were created on the frontend by certain users.  The downside apparently, is that the profile is not automatically created when a user is created. So, while elegant, your solution won't work for me.  Can you suggest another work-around?

Comment: @patrik Check the edit, I create my users from a registration page, No admin view, only by calling $user->save(); and the profile is created immediately, associated to the newly created user. And the override of the save function will allow you to set the user type for every new profile only.

Comment: I'm with you on the override save() function that you provided; I'm just hung up on the $user->save() you mention in the edit.  The way it's set up now, is the form is processed in the actions class... see my update in the question.  It's definitely not creating a user profile once the user is saved outside of the registration process provided by the pluggin.  Also, I don't want every user to be designated with a type '4', just those users created using the frontend app I created.  Does that make any sense?  So I'm not sure what you mean by 'check the edit'.